# How to disable draggable after an item is dropped?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

This is what I have. Right now, when the draggable item is dropped, it can still be moved(dragged) and repositioned. I want to disable each draggable item once it has been dropped.

Here is what I have

```
  $( function() {
    $(".drag").draggable({
    stack: ".drag",
    stop: function() {
      let next = $(this).data('index') + 1;
      $('div[data-index="' + next + '"]').show();
    }
  });
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
     tolerance: "touch",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
      }
    });
  } );
```

Example of my draggable items

```
<div id="drag1" data-index="1" class="drag" style="left:10px;top:20px;background-color:orange">Draggable 1</div>

<div id="drag2" data-index="2" class="drag" style="left:10px;top:20px;background-color:lightblue; display: none;">Draggable 2</div>

<div id="drag3" data-index="3" class="drag" style="left:10px;top:20px;background-color:lightblue; display: none;">Draggable 3</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When the draggable element is dropped then just disable it's drag-ability by using the bellow code

> ui.draggable.draggable({disabled: true});

[Js Fiddle Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikcse20/j9dLnhrp/5)

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
 tolerance: "touch",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
      //debugger;
      //var dragId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      //$("#"+dragId).removeClass("drag"); // If you want to change the class
      ui.draggable.draggable({disabled: true}); // For revoking draggable functionality
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" ).html("Done")
  }
});
```